# How to Redirect using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

So i've built my first app using Devise! I'm pretty stoked, but I would like to know how one goes about having the app re-direct to a specific page after logging in?

In other words,

Instead of logging in, and  remaining at the home page, how do I get rails to redirect to a microposts page for example?

In my case specifically it only redirects to the posts page sometimes, and other times it just stays at the initial home page.

Here is my posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]

  def posts
  @title = "Posts"
  end
end
```

Comment: It actually redirects to the reference page if you tried to visit any without signing in, otherwise redirects to root path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, devise redirects you to the root, you can customize `after_sign_in_path_for` method anyway you like. There's also `after_sign_out_path_for` method at your disposal to customize.

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # extra stuff

  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
    if something
      posts_path
    else
      root_path
    end
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(user)
    new_some_other_path
  end
end
```